# "Dimension too large" error with XY-pic

Tags: errors, xy-pic

What's wrong with the following?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix{
        \text{Long string of text that causes an error during the compilation of this document} \\
        X
}
\end{document}
```

Strangely if there's no second row it compiles fine.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 6):

It seems to be a deficiency of `xypic`, this problem with simple but wide matrix cells. As a workaround, you could reduce the width as `xy` sees it, if the other parts of the matrix wouldn't be affected, such as with `\makebox`:

```
\xymatrix{
        \makebox[.8\textwidth][l]{Long string of  that causes an error during the 
                                  compilation of this document}\\% not any more
        X
}
```